# using mysql_close()

Tags: php, mysql

is it necessary to use  mysql_close() at the end of a query in PHP?

Comment: Do you still need more information in order to accept the answer ?

Answer (score 18):

In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) :

> mysql_close() closes the
>   non-persistent connection to the MySQL
>   server that's associated with the
>   specified link identifier.
>
> **Using mysql_close() isn't usually
>   necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the
>   end of the script's execution.**

More reading about that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct)

Comment: Terminating resources as soon as they're no longer required is always a good practice. If your script is long running holding on to resource you no longer need just brings you closer to resource exhaustion.

Answer (score 5):

Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See also freeing resources.

read more at :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: Performance can be improved by closing as soon as you are done so the handle is available for other processes to use.

Answer (score 3):

As answered by others and the manual, it's not necessary. But if you wonder the use; you usually only want to do this when there is more to come in the PHP script and you want to **ensure** that *another* connection/transaction is to be used then.

Answer (score 1):

No. When the PHP requests ends all resources will be freed, including MySQL connection resources.