# Blank page on mysql connect

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-2002, mysql-error-1040

I have a php function ( "mconnect") for connecting to mysql . Sometimes in full load i get a blank page with "[]mconnect: mysql_connect"
In this function i have custom messages for mysql error 1040 and 2002 -- connection errors
In logs nothing appears when this error occur
I use lighttpd 1.4.28 with php-cgi 5.2.0 and mysql 5.0.32 debian etch

Those blank pages with error appears only in full load : when mysql has Avg. questions per second 
= 586.39 and lighty ~300 conn/s
Both, lighty and mysql share the same machine: dual  quad xeon with 8G ram

If anyone has a clue, please share

Thanks
Cris

Answer (score 0):

You could increase MySQLs connection limit, like pointed out in this article: http://rackerhacker.com/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/

But it would be good if you also had a look over different performance tunning like query caching and the like. As well information I have found on the same website.
http://rackerhacker.com/2008/06/24/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connections/

But the best approach would be to limit the number of database accesses from your application, have some caching in place and do the minimal connections to your database.

Comment: Connection limit is very high , and i use querry cache. Is a production server with many writes. Error 1040 or 2002 has a custom error mesage in our application, when occur. This error i don't know what it is..this is my question

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996976/are-mysql-close-and-pg-close-required

Comment: I don't think, because php-cgi close connection immediate on script finish

Comment: @cris - Check the incoming traffic [traffic spike, resource not enough to handle]. Check lighttpd log on pages that spend long time to generate [when pages take longer time to response, it holding mysql resource]. Best bet to check where are the slow pages come from.