# Automatic db connection close in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following in my config.php file for one of my web app.

```
//db settings
    $host = 'localhost'; //database location
    $user = 'example'; //database username
    $pass = 'example12'; //database password
    $db_name = 'example'; //database name

//create db connection
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);

//sets encoding to utf8
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

I am including `config.php` in all pages of my application at top (1st line of code).

I want to know that will PHP/MYSQL maintain connection open and close automatically or I need to explicitly call them. Connection is opening by itself, as I am doing all db based tasks properly. But not closing connection anywhere, this is a high traffic website.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065282/using-mysql-close

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connection will close automatically upon termination of the script.

The [notes on `mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) state that:

> The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling `mysql_close()`.

Comment: You should close it explicitly when you're done with it, though, unless it's as near as makes no difference.

Comment: I suppose your comment is targeted at me, @MohammadSaberi? The actual PHP script's execution is referred to here. Not the execution of a single query. You'd have to `mysql_connect()` after each query if this'd be the case.

Comment: @LinusKleen, you are right and I was wrong. I mean will closing mysql connection occur after each operation on mysql, or after executing and loading the whole of our web page ?