# Is there a way to override PHP __destruct in parent class from a child class

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, inherited-constructors

I have  declared a  PHP magic function __destruct in child class, when an object from this child class is called it also calls the __destruct from the parent class in addition to the __destruct from the child class.

How do I make sure that only the __destruct in the child class is called.  I do not want to use access modifiers too because I might be creating another child class.

Comment: This might be an opinion, but I don't think you should try this. It's a sign of bad OOP design if you have to. Perhaps you could convince me that I am wrong with a good example?

Comment: Why do you want to suppress the parent class behaviour? Maybe it does something important? As mentioned above, if it's causing you a problem you might want to re-think your design, but it's hard to give definitive advice without any code or context

Comment: Yes, you probably have to redesign it somewhat. The parent class shouldn't (always) be doing things that a child class doesn't want/need.

Comment: I'm confused -- if you have __destruct() in the parent and __destruct() in the child, then the parent won't get called unless you explicitly put `parent::__destruct();` in the child. So just... don't do that? Am I misunderstanding your design?

Comment: Oh okay , thanks maybe I should re-design my code.

Comment: Although using a destructor is totally valid, I think the vast majority of examples that I've seen of people using them seem to be based on a misunderstanding of object life cycles, most commonly [database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644892/231316). I'm not saying your code is wrong (especially since we haven't seen it), I'm just noting past experiences.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, you're right. It works the same as `__construct()`. I went along with the question, but I should have checked. I did now: https://3v4l.org/aYH1L